# Getting new page title with .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

all!

So, I've set up an ajax based site that pulls the new content from a `section`. Here is my code to accomplish that feat.

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
  var isAnimating = false,
      firstLoad   = false;

  $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newPage = $(this).attr('href'),
        newTitle = $(document).attr('title');
    document.title = newTitle;
    if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    if(firstLoad) {
      var newPageArray = location.pathname.split('/'),
        newPage = newPageArray[newPageArray.length - 1];
      if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, false);
    }
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  function changePage(url, bool) {
      isAnimating = true;
      $('body').addClass('transition');
      $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
        loadNewContent(url, bool);
        $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
      });
    if(!transitionsSupported()) loadNewContent(url, bool);
  }

  function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
    var section = $('<section class="content-wrap"></section>');
    section.load(url + ' .content-wrap > *', function(responseText){
    document.title = $(responseText).filter("title").text();    
      $('.wrapper').html(section);
      finishLoad();
      var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('transition').addClass('load');
        $('.loader').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
          isAnimating = false;
          $('.loader').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
        });
        if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
      }, delay);
      if(url!=window.location && bool){
        window.history.pushState({path: url}, '', url);
      }
    });
  }

  window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) window.history.back();
  }

  function transitionsSupported() {
    return $('html').hasClass('csstransitions');
  }

  function finishLoad() {
    $('body').on('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
      $(this).delay(5000).queue(function() { 
        $(this).removeClass('load').dequeue();
      });
    })
  }
});
```

This works like a charm, but I want to know how to make the `.load()` function change the page title. The problem I'm running into is that the new content is simply pulled from a `section` within the new page, so I don't believe that it's able to find the `title` of the new page. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to make this work and change the page title on complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
```

or for an external page, something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: externalURL,
  async: true,
  success: function(data) {
    var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
    alert(matches[0]);
  }   
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to make the function pull the page title dynamically, rather than setting it in the jQuery.